# Better way to do distinct rollup in redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, distinct, rollup

What is the best way to write a query that does a rollup of distinct counts over various discrete time ranges on redshift?

For example, if you have some phone numbers collected for leads in various organizations and want to find out how many distinct phone numbers were created weekly, monthly, quarterly, etc... what is the best way to do it?

This is the best I could come up with:

```
SELECT
  organization,
  sum(weekly) as weekly,
  sum(monthly) as monthly,
  sum(quarterly) as quarterly,
  sum(yearly) as yearly
FROM (
    SELECT 
      organization,
      COUNT(DISTINCT phoneNumber) as weekly,
      null as monthly,
      null as quarterly,
      null as yearly
    FROM Lead
    WHERE createdAt >= current_date - interval '7 days'
    GROUP BY organization

      UNION ALL

    SELECT
      organization,
      null as weekly,
      COUNT(DISTINCT phoneNumber) as monthly,
      null as quarterly,
      null as yearly
    FROM Lead
    WHERE createdAt >= current_date - interval '1 month'
    GROUP BY organization

        UNION ALL

    SELECT
      organization,
      null as weekly,
      null as monthly,
      COUNT(DISTINCT phoneNumber) as quarterly,
      null as yearly
    FROM Lead
    WHERE createdAt >= current_date - interval '3 months'
    GROUP BY organization

        UNION ALL

    SELECT
      organization,
      null as weekly,
      null as monthly,
      null as quarterly,
      COUNT(DISTINCT phoneNumber) as yearly
    FROM Lead
    WHERE createdAt >= current_date - interval '1 year'
    GROUP BY organization
) GROUP BY organization
```

Any way to make the query faster / easier to understand?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make it more likely that your question would be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT organization,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN created_at >= current_date - interval '7 day' THEN phoneNumber END) as weekly,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN created_at >= current_date - interval '1 month' THEN phoneNumber END) as monthly,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN created_at >= current_date - interval '3 month' THEN phoneNumber END) as quarterly,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN created_at >= current_date - interval '1 year' THEN phoneNumber END) as yearly
FROM Lead
WHERE createdAt >= current_date - interval '1 year'
GROUP BY organization;
```

Comment: That would be great, let me try it and see if i get the same result

Comment: Brilliant, the only thing that needed to be changed was that CASE WHEN needs a boolean to decide whether or not to return the then so I changed that bit to "CASE WHEN createdAt >= current_date - interval..."